# Single quotes break my CQL filter

Tags: cql, escaping

I am building a function which creates the CQL filter on the fly based on selections from dropdown menus. 
Then I append the filter in the corresponding KML URL and download the KML file. It works fine but I have noticed that when the data (appended to the CQL) contain quotes then I get a runtime error:

```
Could not parse CQL filter list. Encountered "ar" at line 1, column 18. Was expecting one of: "and" ... "or" ... ")" ... "/" ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... Parsing : (DistrictNa='Man'ar').
```

Is there a way to escape these characters? What is the best strategy to follow?

**EDITED**
I read [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201108.mbox/%3C20110803152250.294300@gmx.net%3E) that I can escape it with another single quote. But in my case I need something more automated than this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what language you trying to use but something like the following should work.

```
public class EscapeCQL {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "Man'ar";
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println(EscapeCQL.escapeCQL(test));
  }

  static public String escapeCQL(String cql) {
    return cql.replace("'", "''");
  }
}
```

And in JavaScript I'd do something like:

```
var cql = "Man'ar";
var res = cql.replace("'", "''");
```

Comment: I see. Well I am getting the data from a Django view and play with them in javascript. So replacing them is they way to go.